# How to read the unread email only in gmail through Aspose.Email for java

Tags: java, email, aspose

we’re trying to read the latest unread messages from Gmail using IMAP using ASPOSE.Email for java.

But we’re unable to fetch latest unread messages. Please provide the java code snippet for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the code snippet given below to read recent unread messages.

```
ImapClient client = new ImapClient();
client.setHost("imap.gmail.com");
client.setPort(993);
client.setUsername("test@gmail.com");
client.setPassword("testPassword");
client.setSecurityOptions(SecurityOptions.SSLAuto);
client.selectFolder(ImapFolderInfo.IN_BOX);

ImapQueryBuilder builder = new ImapQueryBuilder();
// Check for unread messages
builder.hasNoFlags(ImapMessageFlags.isRead());
// set the effective date
builder.getInternalDate().since(new Date("2018/10/05"));
MailQuery query = builder.getQuery();

ImapMessageInfoCollection coll = client.listMessages(query);
for (ImapMessageInfo msgInfo : coll) {
    MailMessage msg = client.fetchMessage(msgInfo.getUniqueId());
    System.out.println("Subject:" + msg.getSubject());
}
```

Note: I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.